# SSLZeroReturnError error only in python 3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, openssl, python-3.10

I use that code to connect for ssl server

```
import socket
import ssl
import sys
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)
ssl_socket.connect((sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])))
```

When I run this code with pyhton3.7 everything if fine

But when I run this code with Python 3.10.4 I got that error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_ssl.py", line 6, in <module>
    ssl_socket.connect((sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1374, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1365, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLZeroReturnError: TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:997)
```

How can I fix that that this code will work with Python 3.10.4?

In python 3.10.4 I have `OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`

In python 3.7 I have `OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022`

Comment: Python 3.10 uses a newer version of OpenSSL which also has different security settings. Your problem is likely related to the server being old and requiring obsolete ciphers or protocol versions. Unfortunately what you show is specific to this server and without knowledge of the server not reproducible and debuggable by others, so no clear recommendations can be given of what is need to support this specific server .